# How to give information between an activity to a fragment in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, helper

I have a Fragment and an Activty, the activity has 3 editText and a Image. You can upload the image from your device. But know i'm trying to connect both fragment and pass all the information from Activity B to Fragment A.

Fragment has a button for edit the profile, 3 TextView and an ImageView, if you click in the button, you go to Activity and in there you have the 3 edit Text (name, email, and description) and you have a button for upload an image from your device. And a last button for save the changes.

I want to save the changes with the save button and give the information of the edittext and the image to the Fragment.

I'm doing in JAVA.

**Fragment File**

```
  public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {
    private static String name;
    private static String mail2;
    private static String des;
    Button btnclose;
    Button btnedit;
    Button btnDisponibles;
    Button btnFinalizadas;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    public NotificationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
     */
    String name2;
    String e_mail;
    String description;
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static NotificationFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        NotificationFragment fragment = new NotificationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(name, param1);
        args.putString(mail2, param2);
        args.putString(des,"");
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            name2 = getArguments().getString("name");
            e_mail = getArguments().getString("email");
            description = getArguments().getString("descripcion");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);
        TextView nombre, email, descripcion;
        nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtNombre);
        email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        descripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtdescripcion);
        nombre.setText(name);
        email.setText(e_mail);
        descripcion.setText(description);

        btnedit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btneditar);
        btnedit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editar();
            }
        });    
        return view;
    }
```

**The Activity file**

```
public class editarperfil extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imagen;
    Button btnchange;
    Button btnout;
    EditText editNombre;
    EditText editEmail;
    EditText ediDescripcion;

    String name;
    String e_mail;
    String description;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editarperfil);
        imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagenId);
        btnchange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnImagen);
        btnchange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cargarimagen();
            }
        });
        btnout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
        btnout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                salir();
            }
        });
    }


    private void cargarimagen(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/");
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccione la aplicación"), 10);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Uri path=data.getData();
        imagen.setImageURI(path);
    }
    private void salir()
    {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", editNombre.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("email", editEmail.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("descripcion", ediDescripcion.getText().toString()); // Put anything what you want

        NotificationFragment fragment2 = new NotificationFragment();
        fragment2.setArguments(bundle);

    }
```

This doesn't work...

PD: How can I do the same if there are two Fragments?

I have this error code

```
05/13 08:41:27: Launching 'app' on Pixel_3a_API_30_x86.
Install successfully finished in 613 ms.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.myapplication29/com.example.myapplication29.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 25724 on device 'Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/myapplication2: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
I/myapplication2: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
W/myapplication2: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
W/myapplication2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
W/myapplication2: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xefcb0590, tid 25802
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xefcaff70: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xefcaff70: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xefff5970) (first time)
I/Gralloc4: mapper 4.x is not supported
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xefcb2270, tid 25802
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3fd40d000 size 0x2000
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_2 
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2188 bytes, containing 1 windows, 12 views
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
    endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
    setComposingRegion on inactive InputConnection
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication29, PID: 25724
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication29.editarperfil.salir(editarperfil.java:76)
        at com.example.myapplication29.editarperfil.access$100(editarperfil.java:28)
        at com.example.myapplication29.editarperfil$2.onClick(editarperfil.java:55)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

use EventBus to transfer data:

1 implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'

2 new a class MessageEvent:

```
public class MessageEvent {

    private Bundle bundle;

    public Bundle getBundle() {
        return bundle;
    }

    public MessageEvent setBundle(Bundle bundle) {
        this.bundle = bundle;
        return this;
    }
}
```

3 in your Activity method:

```
private void salir()
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", editNombre.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("email", editEmail.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("descripcion", ediDescripcion.getText().toString()); // Put anything what you want

    NotificationFragment fragment2 = new NotificationFragment();
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent().setBundle(bundle));// post data 
    loadFragment(fragment2);
}

public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment  ) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.navigation_notifications, fragment);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

4 in your NotificationFragment add methods:

```
public class NotificationFragment extends Fragment {
 
    @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN,sticky = true)
    public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
        Bundle bundle = event.getBundle();
        if (bundle != null) {
            name2 = bundle.getString("name");
            e_mail = bundle.getString("email");
            description = bundle.getString("descripcion");
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageEvent: " + bundle);
    };

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }
}
```

One EventBus post can be received by multi @Subscribe .

---

Change code of your activity:

```
private void salir()
{
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", editNombre.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("email", editEmail.getText().toString());
    bundle.putString("descripcion", ediDescripcion.getText().toString()); // Put anything what you want

    NotificationFragment fragment2 = new NotificationFragment();
    fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
    loadFragment(fragment2);
}

public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment  ) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.navigation_notifications, fragment);
    transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: But here `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity"); ` I can put this?

Comment: `Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString("name", editNombre.getText().toString());`

Comment: I update the code but it's still not working

Comment: It should be 'public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflat getArguments()  '     .    and 'getArgument' should inside 'onCreateView"

Comment: But i have my code like yours and it doesn't work look at the top are the same code. I not following you ar the moment can you explain me in other way please?

Comment: Hi @AlexDeveloper99,i updated my answer,pls kindly refer.

Comment: Hi @shirley this code doesn't work for me, i'm very surprised. The text doesn't appear and i don't know how to do it

Comment: Hi @AlexDeveloper99,`eventbus` and `setArguments` are two different method,[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgUAJ.png) is `setArguments` ,the original method.

Comment: I see but where i put the `eventbus` ? Because you say in the activity, and in there I have the `setArgument` method....

Comment: And in the step 4 `4 in your NotificationFragment add methods:` with that  I print in the TextViews of that fragment?

Comment: That's two different methods. It can be tested independently or at the same time.```NotificationFragment fragment2 = new NotificationFragment();
    fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
    EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(new MessageEvent().setBundle(bundle));// post data 
    loadFragment(fragment2);```This allows you to use tests at the same time.

Comment: I have an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232325/discussion-between-alexdeveloper99-and-shirley).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bundle.

For Send Value

```java
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Key", "value");

fragmentObject.setArgument(bundle);
--Start or replace fragment---
```

For get values

```java
String value = getArgument().getString("key");
```

you didnt write code for open or replace fragment. Without commit of framgnet your fragment class will  enable to execute. and get value

Comment: what is the code for start or replace fragment? Because I don't know that im very new in this world

Comment: use this link. this will give you brief information about fragment in android
https://www.javatpoint.com/android-fragments

Comment: Thank but my fragment has a OnCreateView, and Oncreate what are you telling me at the moment? Sorry but i'm not following you...

Comment: In your FromFragment:

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(TAG_MY_CLASS, myClass);
Fragment toFragment = new ToFragment();
toFragment.setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.body, toFragment, TAG_TO_FRAGMENT)
    .addToBackStack(TAG_TO_FRAGMENT).commit();

in your ToFragment:

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle args = getArguments();

Comment: Hi @Milan this isn't work for me I have an Activity